# What is mining intensity?

Tags: cgminer, miner-configuration

Both Bitcoin and Litecoin have an intensity setting when mining.  What does this mean?

Comment: Are you using a mining program other than the standard client? If so, what?

Comment: I am using cgminer.  Maybe this setting is specifically related to GPU mining?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is related to GPU mining. From [cgminer's README](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/GPU-README#L95):

> INTENSITY INFORMATION:
>
> Intensity correlates with the size of work being submitted at any one
>   time to a GPU. The higher the number the larger the size of work.
>   Generally speaking finding an optimal value rather than the highest
>   value is the correct approach as hash rate rises up to a point with
>   higher intensities but above that, the device may be very slow to
>   return responses, or produce errors.

I would just leave it set to 'dynamic,' or `--intensity d` . That will adjust it automatically depending on how long it takes to complete work.
<sub>([nitty-gritty details](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/v3.7.2/driver-opencl.c#L536))</sub>

Comment: previous answer is not valid to the question. --intensity is can be followed by number(s), certain ones. Which numbers are valid and what they mean were not answered. The question was "Both Bitcoin and Litecoin have an intensity setting when mining. What does this mean?"

Comment: @ClarkTaylor It means pretty much exactly what I quoted. If there's a part of that that's unclear, I need you to be more specific about it.